# Issues sending data using axios in react native

Tags: javascript, laravel, react-native, axios

I am having issue sending a put request.
I have tested the api using postman, when I send the request with a body of form-data and header of content-type ( application/json ), it doesn't work, infact when i dump the request, I realize nothing was sent, but again in postman if i send the request using body of raw, it works successfully, now bringing the same thing to my react native project using axios to make the same request, I get the same error as when I used form-data in postman, nothing get sent and I get error 500 (bad request).
So now in the backend, I used put the request under if, so when I run the function, I get success, but nothing get sent.
The thing is it sends nothing, no input at all is sent.

This is the function right here;

```
const setBasic = () => async ({ id }) => {
const data = new FormData();
data.append('Basic', 1)


const config = {
    method: 'put',
    url: `http://89bb1d61.ngrok.io/api/usersub/${id}`,
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" }

}

const response = await axios(config)
if (response) {
    console.log(response.data)
} else {
    console.log('Error')
}
```

}

But nothing gets sent.

This is the server side code;

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);

    if($request->has('Basic')){
        $user->Basic = $request->input('Basic');
        }
    //  $user->Basic = $request->input('Basic');
    if($request->has('Standard')){
        $user->Standard = $request->input('Standard');
        }
    if($request->has('Premium')){
        $user->Premium = $request->input('Premium');
        }




     $user->save();


     return response()->json([
      'message' => 'Success',

  ]);
}
```

It will return the success message here, (I console logged response.data) but this is because I had wrapped **if** around the requests. If I were to remove the **if** , then bad request, the input isn't received.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing it this way;

```
const setBasic = () => async ({ id }) => {
    const Basic = 1
    const response = await appApi.put(`/usersub/${id}`, { Basic });
    if (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }
}
```